# Rotating a texture around x, y, z axis and Using it to draw a polygon

Tags: actionscript-3, air, rotation, adobe

I'm trying to draw an arbitrary polygon with a transformed texture with [Graphics API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) .

Here's what I'm trying to do in 3 steps:

First, I have a texture (as a BitmapData)

[image]

Second, Transform the texture - Tile it and rotate it around x, y or z axis. (y-axis for now).

[image]

Third, Draw a polygon using the transformed texture.

[image]

I could rotate it around z-axis with the code below:

```
var gr:Graphics = sp.graphics;
gr.clear();
var mat:Matrix = new Matrix();
mat.scale( 0.5, 0.5 );
mat.rotate( angle );
gr.beginBitmapFill( bd, mat, true, true );
gr.moveTo( points[0].x, points[0].y );
for ( var lp1:int = 1; lp1 < points.length; lp1++ )
    gr.lineTo( points[lp1].x, points[lp1].y );
gr.lineTo( points[0].x, points[0].y );
gr.endFill();
```

But I couldn't rotate the texture around x or y axis as it requires some sort of projection I guess.

I thought about drawing a rotated Bitmap object onto a BitmapData and using it as a texture:

```
var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap( bd );
bmp.rotationY = angle;
var transformedBd:BitmapData = new BitmapData( 256, 256, true, 0 );
transformedBd.draw( bmp );
… and call gr.beginBitmapFill() with the transformedBd …
```

But with this code, the texture won't be tiled.

I also looked at drawTriangles() method but AFIK, it only let me draw a rotated polygon, not a polygon with rotated texture.

If anyone has insights on this issue, please share.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest first creating a polygon filled with a repeating bitmapdata. Then you can just transform the whole polygon container using rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but that's a transformed polygon with a tiled texture. I want a polygon with a transformed texture. I have a specific requirement to fill & draw a polygon in 2d space with a transformed texture.

Comment: A transform matrix cannot be used other than rotate around the Z axis. AFAIK you cannot create a full 3D projection on raw bitmapdata without using either a container or some sort of 3D engine like Away3D. Even when using Away3D, you're creating 3D polygons and putting 2D textures in them. The difference is that Away3D renders it all in a huge bitmapdata instead of in a separate movieclip or sprite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can:

1. put your 2D Texture inside a Sprite or other container
2. 3D transform that container, for example by using

   myContainer.rotationX = 20;
   myContainer.rotationY = 200;

3 - then you create a new BitmapData()
4 - and you DRAW the entire myContainer into the bitmapdata.

```
myBitmapData.draw(myContainer, myMatrix, myColorTransform, blendMode, myRectangle, smooth);
```

5 - and finally you delete the original 2D texture and myContainer.

Voila, you now have a 3d transformed texture inside a single bitmapdata.